# how can i have a right alignment menu fill top in WPF

Tags: wpf, menu, alignment, dock

I’m new in WPF. I want a right alignment menu. But when set horizontalalignment property to right, it don’t fill the whole width of row. I use horizontalcontentalignment as stretch but it does’nt work. This is my code:

```
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
            <MenuItem Header="_File"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help"/>
        </Menu> 
     </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

What is displayed is as below:

```
    -----------------------------
    File edit help              |
    -----------------------------
```

But  I want to be:

```
   ---------------------------------
                     Help edit file|
    --------------------------------
```

How can I get menu fill top and set it’s alignment to right?

Comment: Dock should be in row 0, no?

Comment: yes you're right i edit the code and i forget to change it

Comment: Is the grid inside something else?, I pasted this code on VS 2010 and seems to look the way you want it

Comment: no it's not fill all row it's just right alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>

        <MenuItem Header="_File" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Help"/>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```